# Error: Method not allowed in REST wcf Api

Tags: c#, wcf

I have written an API with this format:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "Get", UriTemplate = "/GetPrice/{ItemID}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
string GetVegatablePrice(string ItemID);
```

I got an error:

> method not allowed

Comment: Can we create Rest api using WCF? as per my knowledge we can create SOAP api which returns xml values using WCF services. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar We can create both REST and SOAP APIs using WCF

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got answer for this.

## Solution

Just change method name to `"GET"`.

While writing an `Http` method, make sure to write in uppercase, like:

- `"GET"`
- `"PUT"`
- `"POST"`
- `"DELETE"`